# Characteristic properties for topological pushouts and pullbacks

Tags: general-topology

So far in my topology class we've talked about several topological constructions (namely the subspace topology, the quotient topology, the (finite and infinite) product topology, and the disjoint union topology). In each case we had some sort of "characteristic property" to associate to each. For instance, the characteristic property of the subspace topology is

> If $A$ is a subspace of $X$, and $T$ is another topological space, then a function $f:T \rightarrow A$ is continuous $\iff$ $i_A \circ f$ is continuous, where $i_A:A \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion function.

Another example is for the product topology:

> If $X,Y,T$ are topological spaces, then the functions $f:T \rightarrow X$, $g:T\rightarrow Y$ are continuous $\iff$  $(f,g): T \rightarrow X \times Y$ is continuous (the projection functions lurk in the background).

I would like to know if there is a characteristic property for the pullback and the pushout of topological spaces, and if it is in the form of the statements above (namely in the form of an "if and only if" statement that gives a condition for detecting the continuity of certain maps).

I have some idea of what the maps that come with spaces are (e.g., I think in the case of pushouts, the two associated maps are maps that are compositions: the injection of a set into a disjoint union, composed with a quotient map into the disjoint union modulo an equivalence relation), however I'm not sure what the corresponding properties are.

Thanks in advance for any help! Please let me know if the question is imprecise or unclear.

Comment: Pushouts and pullbacks can be defined in a general category, so you might be interested in looking at the category theoretic definition.

Comment: Ah yes! I took a look at the Wikipedia articles for both of them (in the general category theory setting). I'm having difficulty translating the universal properties given there into statements of the form that I'm looking for.

Comment: There is a category of topologies, Top, where the objects are topological spaces and the morphisms are continuous maps. So if you just make the necessary terminology replacements, that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I think I'm getting stuck with thinking about what the maps I "care about" are. For the subspace and product topologies, I "care" about maps into the subspace/product. Similarly, for the quotient and disjoint union topologies, I "care" about functions out of the quotient/disjoint union...I suspect I'm supposed to look at functions into the pushout/functions out of the pullback? I'll try to formulate an answer to this after some sleep. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's exactly the reverse, actually.

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Zhen Lin is correct. For subspace topologies, you can think of a subspace A as being embedded in a bigger space B. In other words a subspace topology is characterized by a continuous injection f:A -> B between topological spaces. Note that in the category Top, injections correspond to monomorphisms.

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Similary for quotient topologies, you are identifying elements in a parent topology P to get a quotient topology Q, so you should expect f:P->Q instead of f:Q->P, so we can write f(a)=f(b) and the like. Then since the image of f should be Q, we need f to be surjective (an epimorphism in Top). It is interesting to note that the subspace topology and quotient topology are dual to each other. Why? If you can convince yourself, then you probably can handle product and disjoint union characterizations yourself.

Comment: (Still working on this, btw. Got sidelined studying for an exam). Thanks for the tip. I think the duality comes from the fact that in the subspace topology, the characterizing function (the continuous injection) leaves the subspace, whereas the characterizing function for the quotient topology (the associated quotient map) maps onto the quotient. Same for product and disjoint unions with the projections/injections, respectively.

Comment: @b-wilson: And how about this for an attempt at the pushout: Let $X, Y, Z, T$ be topological spaces with continuous functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: X \rightarrow Z$. Let $P$ denote the pushout of $Y$ and $Z$ and let $p_Y$ and $p_Z$ be the canonical maps from $Y$ and $Z$ into $P$, respectively. Then the functions $j: Y \rightarrow T$ and $k: Z \rightarrow T$ (where $j \circ f = k \circ g$) are continuous if and only if the (unique) map $h: P \rightarrow T$ (where $h \circ p_Y = j$ and $h \circ p_Z = k)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Looks like you got it, sir. Note that it is crucial for the combined maps to all be continuous and that h be unique; I think this is what you were intending to say though.

Comment: @b-wilson Yeah, forgot to mention that! Thanks for all the help. Final question: Does this same formulation work on the category of groups or vector spaces over a field or etc.? I.e., does it make sense to "so-and-so is a group homomorphism if and only if this-other-thing is a group homomorphism"? I've only seen the characteristic/universal properties phrased like this in topology.

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Basically, yes. These constructions work any any category as long as the relevant diagrams commute. Often these constructions correspond to more familiarly named constructions. As an exercise, try to see what pullbacks, pushouts, etc are in the category Set of sets.